# Google analytics user property react-ga4

Tags: google-analytics-4, react-ga

I'm using react-ga4.
I wonder how i could send user properties using this library and set it up in the google analytics panel as I think that i'm doing something wrong.

This is how i initialize ReactGA4

```
ReactGA.initialize(
      [
        {
          trackingId: id,
          gaOptions: {
            role: userRole,
          }
        },
      ]
)
```

any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends what user properties that you want to send. You can send custom user properties that not [reserved](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/user-properties?client_type=gtag#reserved_names) by Google.

For example, I want to send `account_verified` with boolean value and `name` with string value in user property.
You can use `ReactGA.gtag(...args)` in this library, and then you can use it directly or put it into `utils/analytics.js` and wrap it to export function with parameter, so you can use it whenever it needs.

```
import ReactGA from "react-ga4";


ReactGA.gtag("set", "user_properties", {
   account_verified: true,
});

ReactGA.gtag("set", "user_properties", {
   name: "John",
});
```

or

```
import ReactGA from "react-ga4";


export const setAccountProperty = (value: boolean) => {
  ReactGA.gtag("set", "user_properties", {
    account_verified: value,
  });
};

export const setNameProperty = (value: string) => {
  ReactGA.gtag("set", "user_properties", {
    name: value,
  });
};
```

After that, you can check in your Google Analytics in [DebugView](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7201382) directly to ensure your user properties works well.